# Как собрать JS движок v8 для Windlows7 VisualStudio2017 (статические библиотеки (lib))

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2017, lib, x86-64, v8

Добрый день!

Нужен встроенный в проект (C++, Visual Studio2017, Windows7 x64) модуль интерпретации JavaScript, выбор остановился на Google-овском движке v8. Предполагалось собрать несколько статических библиотек и подключить их (к основному проекту).

Вопрос состоит в том: как собрать v8 *.lib файлы (Visual Studio2017, Windows7 x64)?

Результаты предыдущих попыток были примерно следующие:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В лучшем случае, случайно получались пара-тройка lib-файлов, например v8_libbase.lib, v8_libplatform.lib.

Делал согласно следующей документации -https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Building-from-Source - насколько понимаю, официальный вариант.

Также, пробовал смотреть другие источники и выполнять сборку согласно ним. Насколько понял, проект v8, в своём развитии, в разные времена использовал различные средства сборки, например в ~2009м доля этого использовался SCons (на Win7_64 - выдал ошибку при установке), потом Gyp, сейчас, если не ошибаюсь, Gn. Естественно, два последних я пытался использовать (с опорой на документацию по ним).

В случае с gn, помимо консольного варианта (см. результат выше), пробовал сгенерировать решение VS2017, при сборке которого результат был аналогичен (см. выше консоль).

Возможно, я что-то упустил, но что именно - точно сказать не могу.
Хотелось бы получить точные указания - как именно следует собирать v8 (наиболее новую стабильную версию) для Win7-64, static_library и какие именно lib-файлы должны получиться в результате сборки.

Заранее благодарю за ответы.

Несколько вещей, для конкретики, которые я забыл указать ранее, но которые подразумеваются (подразумевается использование для сборки Gn):
- Уже установлена Windows SDK 10.0.16299.15;
- распакован архив "depot_tools.zip" в D:\DepotTools (т.к. на диске C находится ОС);
- уже обновил depot tools, используя в cmd команду `gclient`;
- использовал `fetch v8` и `cd v8` (находясь в D:\DepotTools);
- выполнил `gclient sync`;
- и запустил следующее:

```
gn gen out.gn/x64.release --args='is_debug=false target_cpu="x64" 
target_os="win" static_library=true"
```

потом:

```
ninja -C out.gn/x64.release
```

Переменные окружения:
 [image: см. здесь]

Comment: Способа именно "собрать" v8 для windows 7_64 VS2017, мне, пока что, найти так и не удалось, но удалось найти способ получить уже собранные, рабочие, static libraries v8. Готовые статические библиотеки v8 можно найти в NuGet. При скачивании чего-либо для C++ с NuGet, загруженное можно, обычно, найти в папке "packages", а путь к .lib и .h прописать как $(SolutionDir)packages/<путь>. Надеюсь, это поможет, если кто-либо столкнётся с проблемой получения v8 .lib .  Но, вопрос именно "сборки" v8 из исходников - остаётся пока открытым.

Comment: Здравствуйте, подскажите, Вам удалось в итоге собрать из исходников V8 ? Такая же проблема :(